# How to select document which does not consict some field in Mongo use Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have data:

```
"_id" : 1,
"employee_id_list" : [
    {
        "employee_id" : 2
        "date_end" : 2014-11-13
    },
    {
        "employee_id" : 3
    } 
]
```

And I want select document with `'_id':1` where `employee_id_list` does not consit object with field `date_end`. For example, I want to select only:

```
"_id" : 1,
"employee_id_list" : [
    {
        "employee_id" : 3
    } 
]
```

I use this Java-code:

```
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("employee_service");
DBCollection collectionProject = database.getCollection("project");
DBObject projectMongoObject = new BasicDBObject();
projectMongoObject.put("company_id", 1);
DBCuresor cursorProject = collectionProject.find(projectMongoObject);
```

But I select document with all records in `employee_id_list`.

Comment: Use the `$exists` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the [exists Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) inside an [elemMatch Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to your query.

```
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("employee_service");
DBCollection collectionProject = database.getCollection("project");
DBObject projectMongoObject = new BasicDBObject();
projectMongoObject.put("company_id", 1);
//add this
projectMongoObject.put("employee_id_list", 
        new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", 
        new BasicDBObject("date_end", 
        new BasicDBObject("$exits", false))));
DBCuresor cursorProject = collectionProject.find(projectMongoObject);
```

Comment: and how to specify `$elemMath` for `date_end` field?

Comment: @user3629171: added the missing part.